# PHP create filepath folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mkdir

i want to create with PHP filepath folder. What do i mean?

For example I have the link 
**example.com/Test/One/Two/Three/index.php?id=asdjasdsad**

I want to have on my htaccess error page that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` should be get from another page **(example2.com/Test/One/Two/Three/index.php)**

So i dont know how to code that. I know that I can echo the content with `file_gets_content("http://example2.com/". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` 
but i also want that the file should get saved.

If I use

```
 $filename= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$content = file_get_contents("example.com. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], true);

file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

and there are folder i want that the folder also get created

How can i do that?

Thanks

EDIT:

Comment: Wanted to add, i have no reputation (or not enough) so i cant post more then 2 Links

Comment: are you trying to read a file , get its contents and write into another file ? what htaccess is doing here ? can you have a url like that ?

Comment: yes i want to force file_put_contents to create the file

Comment: give the root or relative file  path , not the http url kind of path . it will work if you have permission to write .